# React-bootstrap offcanvas is built outside React DOM tree (how to fit height to real parent container?)

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-bootstrap

I am creating a React app with an Offcanvas that initially takes up less than the viewport. When a user clicks "Launch Offcanvas" my react-bootstrap component which is wrapped by the App component is expected to show in this parent, i.e. the App component. Here is my code sandbox, which hopefully is reproducible for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/0kex8f?file=/src/App.js

My problem: the offcanvas gets built outside the React DOM tree, and takes up the entire viewport height.

[image]

However, as can be seen, the offcanvas takes up the entire viewport height. I'd like it to always fit within the parent container, if possible. Looking at the DOM tree that React builds, I can also see that the Offcanvas component is built not only outside the App Component, but also outside the App's container, i.e. the root DOM.

[image]

P.S.: The "Maximize" button here is not working as the sandbox is somehow blocking it, but I kept it to substantiate the React app resize situation.